# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile)

Tags: java, maven

Ao clicar no `install` em qualquer um das minhas três partes MVC, ele faz referência ao erro citado.

```
================================================================================
 Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Zeladoria Front-End 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ front-end ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ front-end ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to C:\Users\eduardo\Desktop\categorias_novo\Versao 3.8 Rodrigo\zeladoria-all\front-end\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.875 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-19T09:38:18-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project front-end: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\..\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
================================================================================
```

Ou seja ela não me permite instalar para poder rodar no Jetty/Apache. Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Desde que o ambiente esteja corretamente configurado, JAVA_HOME, PATH e M2_HOME configurados, testar no CMD, com a opção -U, para forçar a baixar os updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto acontece por que para compilar o código é necessário um `JDK`, não um `JRE`, que é o que está sendo usado pois, ou está no `PATH`, ou é o padrão configurado na sua IDE.

Veja este trecho:

> tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31..\lib\tools.jar

O `tools.jar` só existe no `JDK`, que uma biblioteca não presente no *core* java e que contém utilitários para o `JDK`, inclusive para a compilação. Para solucionar isto você deve antes instalar um `JDK` e então depois configurá-lo.

Caso este usando o maven "*embutido*", por exemplo no eclipse, basta ir em `Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Installed JREs` e se não existir um `JDK` adicionado, basta clicar em `Add...` e escolher o diretório do `JDK`. Veja imagem:

[image: Adicionar JDK no Eclipse IDE]

Caso esteja usando pela linha de comando, configura `JAVA_HOME` para o diretório do `JDK` (algo como `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31` instalado.

Na linha de comando você precisará também configura a variável de ambiente `PATH`, adicionando a ela `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Comment: Muito obrigado! É que eu tinha apagado a metadata e por isso ele estava rodando no JRE e não na JDK. Feito o devido add, agora roda de boa.

Comment: Tranquilo @user25240. Caso tenha sido útil, peço que considere aceitar a resposta :)

Comment: Primeira postagem aqui, como faço pra aceitar a sua resposta?

Comment: @user25240 dê uma olhada no [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), lá explica certinho ;)

Comment: Resposta aceita!

Comment: Vc saberia me dizer se agora por estar dando erro nos imports se teria algo a ver com isso? Visto que é o mesmo projeto no qual eu estava trabalhando antes.

Comment: @user25240 Quais *imports*? Se for de alguma dependência, veja se a dependência esta sendo resolvida corretamente. Se for preciso inclua uma nova pergunta.